# React Native + Firebase - Cookies

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native

I am creating the privacy policy of my App. Something I have to handle are ‘cookies’.

Are there cookies on React Native?
How can I see them? I thought it was only possible to use AsyncStorage. Does Firebase use cookies for Auth/Analytics on RN?

Answer (score 1):

i hope you are using RN firebase for integrating firebase on react native, as the documentation cites

> On web based applications, the Firebase Web SDK takes advantage of features such as cookies and local storage to persist the users authenticated state across sessions. The native Firebase SDKs also provide this functionality using device native SDKs, ensuring that a users previous authentication state between app sessions is persisted.

- https://rnfirebase.io/auth/usage

they are using the typical storage mechanisms to store token respective to platform, it internally uses *Shared Preferences* for android and *KeyChain* for IOS.